# How to properly set admob in android?

Tags: android, admob

I tried for hours to set Admob in my application but I'm getting the error code 3. here are the steps I followed :

- In the admob interface I clicked on 'monetize a new app' then 'Add an application manually'
- For the application's name I put the same in the manifest :

  ```
  android:label="NameApp"
  ```
- Then I choose the ads' type (banner)
- Then admob ask for the package's name I put the 'applicationID' attribute available in the gradle file
- I obtained an ID. I put this id here :

<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pubXXXXXX-XXX</string>

- And to finish, I use this code :

  ```
  MobileAds.initialize(this.getContext(), getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
  AdView mAdView = (AdView) v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
  ```
- In XML :

  ```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      android:id="@+id/adView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="25dp">
  </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
  ```

And when i run the app. I obtain 'Failed to load ad: 3'. Note that when I use the banner in test mode it works. I think that the error is in the package's name.

Comment: Is the application has to be on the playstore to receive an add ? Because now I'm getting the error code 0.

Comment: Nope, not really but sometimes it happens depending on your geographical position. If it works in test mode, normally it should work in production too.

Comment: So if I do understand I just have to wait for the ads. Right ?

Comment: You were right. It works now.